# Gensim word2vec saves numpy arrays?

Tags: numpy, gensim, word2vec

I am running the Word2Vec implementation from gensim twice, and I have a problem with the `save` function:

```
model_ = gensim.models.Word2Vec(all_doc, size=int(config['MODEL']['embed_size']),
                                window=int(config['MODEL']['window']),
                                workers=multiprocessing.cpu_count(),
                                sg=1, iter=int(config['MODEL']['iteration']),
                                negative=int(config['MODEL']['negative']),
                                min_count=int(config['MODEL']['min_count']), seed=int(config['MODEL']['seed']))
```

`model_.save(config['BASIC']['embedding_dir'])`

I obtain different outputs for each time I run it. The first time it gives an "output_embedding", an "output_embedding.trainables.syn1neg.npy" and an "output_embedding.wv.vectors.npy". But the second time it does not give the two npy files, it just generates "output_embedding".

The only thing I change from the first to the second time is the sentences I use as input (`all_doc`).

Why it does not generate the 3 files ?

Answer (score 0):

Gensim only creates the separate files when the size of the internal numpy arrays is over a certain threshold – so I suspect your `all_doc` corpus has a very small vocabulary in one case, and a more typically large vocabulary in the other.

When it does generate multiple files, be sure to keep them all together for later loads to work.

(If for some urgent reason you needed to change that behavior, [the inherited `.save()` method takes an optional `sep_limit` argument to change the threshold](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/utils.html#gensim.utils.SaveLoad.save) - but I'd recommend against mucking with this.)

Separately: that your file names have `.trainables.` in them suggests you're using a pre-4.0.0 version of Gensim. There've been some improvements to `Word2Vec` & related algorithms in the latest Gensim, and some older code will need small changes to keep working, so you may want to upgrade to the latest version before building any more functionality on an older base.

Comment: Thank you @gojomo! I was looking for this in the documentation, but I couldn't get to the site you quoted, and here: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.save, it was not specified.